# set icon based on file extention. Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, font-awesome

I'm working with Angular 7, and I have a list where I display some document names with an icon. At this momento I'm displaying the same icon no mather what document is, but I have icons for Excel document, pdf, doc, image, etc. I want to know if is there a way to set the icon based on the document extention.

So far I have it like this:
[image]

With html like this:

```
<h6 class="list-tittle">
  Documentos
</h6>
<div >
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let document of documents;" class="list-item"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="color:#5cb85c;" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{document}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn  tolowercase">Agregar Documento</button>
<h6 class="list-tittle">
  Anexos
</h6>
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let anexo of anexos;" class="list-item"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" style="color:#5cb85c;" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{anexo}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn  tolowercase">Agregar Anexo</button>
```

And the expected behaviour is that the list display the icons like this:
EXPECTED:
[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you have to do following things

1) Extract extension of each document

2) make an array containing icon class name with each type

use below example

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  documentList = ["document1.pdf", "document2.xlsx", "document3.jpg"];
  iconList = [ // array of icon class list based on type
    { type: "xlsx", icon: "fa fa-file-excel-o" },
    { type: "pdf", icon: "fa fa-file-pdf-o" },
    { type: "jpg", icon: "fa fa-file-image-o" }
  ];

  getFileExtension(filename) { // this will give you icon class name
    let ext = filename.split(".").pop();
    let obj = this.iconList.filter(row => {
      if (row.type === ext) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    if (obj.length > 0) {
      let icon = obj[0].icon;
      return icon;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let filename of documentList"> 
      <i class="{{getFileExtension(filename)}}" style="color:#5cb85c;" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      {{filename}}
</div>
```

Working example link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bexr3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the code to work with Font Awesome 5 abd added word to the extensions:

```
iconList = [ // array of icon class list based on type
    { type: "docx", icon: "fas fa-file-word" },
    { type: "xlsx", icon: "fas fa-file-excel" },
    { type: "pdf", icon: "fas fa-file-pdf" },
    { type: "jpg", icon: "fas fa-file-image" }
  ];

getFileExtension(filename : string) : string { 
    let ext = filename.split(".").pop();
    let obj = this.iconList.filter(row => {
      if (row.type === ext) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    if (obj.length > 0) {
      let icon = obj[0].icon;
      return icon;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
```